# Preventing double api calls from a duplicated component in transclusion (only one of them is shown)

Tags: angular

I'm using transclusion in angular to define a fixed view template and define slots for dynamic content.

The component is app-filter-details and its template is:

```
<div id="details-wrapper">
    <div class="details-nav-bar">
        {{ navbarContent }}
    </div>
    <div class="details-wrapper">
        <div class="details-top">
            <ng-content select="filter-details-title"></ng-content>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="!mobile()>
            <ng-content select="filter-details-content"></ng-content>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<app-bottom-sheet *ngIf="mobile() && mapStateService.isMaximized()">
    <div class="details-body moute-scrollable">
        <ng-content select="filter-details-content-bottomsheet"></ng-content>
    </div>
</app-bottom-sheet>
```

And then other components use it like this one:

```
<app-filter-details (backClicked)="goBack()" [whiteBackground]="true">
    <filter-details-title>
        {{ contentOfDetailsTitle }}
    </filter-details-title>
    <filter-details-content>
        <app-whatever-content></app-whatever-component>
    </filter-details-content>
    <filter-details-content-bottomsheet>
        <app-whatever-content></app-whatever-component>
    </filter-details-content-bottomsheet>
</app-filter-details>
```

That basically loads the content of `filter-details-title`, `filter-details-content` and `filter-details-content-bottomsheet`. And what I do is to set **always the same content** to `filter-details-content` and `filter-details-content-bottomsheet` and it will show one or another depending on whether seen from a mobile screen:

```
mobile() {
    return (window.innerWidth <= 576);
}
```

So far so good, it loads the content of both and only one is shown depending on the window width. The problem is that this component of the content `app-whatever-content` is loaded twice and it performs some api calls on init. I can see that all the api calls are made twice (once for the component at the bottomsheet and once for the other).

The changes in mobile version are not just reordering the component, it's a complete different layout, on the mobile it shows floating emulating a bottom sheet ( material.io/components/sheets-bottom ) whereas in non-mobile is shown inside the parent component.

Is there a way I could either load just one of the two components or prevent it from doing the extra api calls somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The problem

You want your filter to be rendered in different places in your layout depending on screen size.

### Your current solution

Your child control takes care of the layout - GOOD

Your child control asks for multiple versions of your filter - BAD

### Why is this bad?

The second point is bad because you want to maintain a single instance of the filter component for performance reasons.

If we were think about how your child component as having an API (which it effectively does), it would look like this:

```js
child: {
  title: string;
  filterTop: FilterComponent;
  filterBottom: FilterComponent;
}
```

This is a poor design in any language*, since the parent doesn't care about where the filter is rendered, it just cares about passing in the filter. Your implementation has leaked out of your child component.

*In any kind of OO language we would pass the same reference if we wanted to refer to a single instance. Unfortunately we're talking about HTML here.

### So what's the solution?

The solution to passing in a single instance is to only pass in one instance. That sounds obvious, but the reasons behind it are more interesting. You should think about simplifying your child component's API and think in distinct elements.

Question:

> What components does my child need?

Answer:

> A title and a filter!

The answer probably isn't "A title, and one filter per breakpoint".

Your parent component should look a bit more like this when you're done:

```html
<app-filter-details (backClicked)="goBack()" [whiteBackground]="true">
    <filter-details-title>
        {{ contentOfDetailsTitle }}
    </filter-details-title>
    <filter-details>
        <app-whatever-content></app-whatever-component>
    </filter-details>
</app-filter-details>
```

There are at least 3 solutions I can think of here

1. Manually attach the filter to a parent in the DOM depending on the screensize.

Yuck - this isn't very Angular.

2. CSS - flexbox ordering + media queries

Depending on the complexity of your layout (I assume you've simplified it for the question), use flexbox and media queries to reorder the container elements inside your child component. If you are using a CSS framework, they may already have utilities for this.

Simple demo of reordering (using class rather than media query):

```js
var container = document.getElementById('container');
var toggle = document.getElementById('toggle');
toggle.addEventListener('click', toggleOrder);

function toggleOrder() {
  container.classList.toggle('reorder'); 
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.reorder .first {
  order: 3;
}

.reorder .third {
  order: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" class="container">
<div class="first">
 1
</div>
<div class="second">
 2
</div>
<div class="third">
 3
</div>
</div>

<button id="toggle">
  Toggle order
</button>
```

3. Store your filter state in a service (and keep your current layout)

This is probably the most Angular solution. Your service is responsible for storing the current state. Your filter control is responsible for instructing the service to make new API requests (after a user-driven event). Your parent is responsible for instructing the service to make the first API request on load (if relevant).

The key to this is separating the idea of a service subscription being directly responsible for an HTTP request. You can simply use a pattern similar to this to split subscriptions from requests for data:

```js
export class SearchService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  // TODO: emit null value when parent component is destroyed?
  private search$: Subject<SearchResults> = new ReplaySubject<SearchResults>(1);

  subscribeSearchResults(): Observable<SearchResults> {
    return this.search$.asObservable();
  }

  submitSearchRequest(criteria): void {
    const url = this.getSearchUrl(criteria); // TODO: implement

    this.http.get<SearchCriteria>(url).subscribe(response => {
      this.search$.next(response);
    });
  }
}
```

And your component would interact with the service like this:

```js
results: SearchResults;

private destroyed: Subject<void> = new Subject<void>();

ngOnInit() {
  this.searchService.subscribeSearchResults().pipe(
    takeUntil(this.destroyed)
  ).subscribe(result => {
    this.results = results;
  });
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.destroyed.next();
  this.destroyed.complete();
}

onSearchSubmit(): void {
  this.searchService.submitSearchRequest(this.criteria);
}
```

### Conclusion

My preference would be solution 2. It is a UI problem which can be solved with a simple UI solution. Solution 3 would require a fair amount of extra code and potential pain.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer. The problem here is that is not just reordering the order, it's a complete different layout, on the mobile it shows floating emulating a bottom sheet ( material.io/components/sheets-bottom ) whereas in non-mobile is shown inside the parent component. And I try to subscribe to the api calls in the component as this way is easy to unsubscribe them in case the component is destroyed so I'm not sure if I can do the same with a service.

Comment: I've updated solution 3 to show a simple example of how you might separate the idea of component subscriptions from making http requests.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could create an input and pass if it's shown in mobile.

```
@Input() showInMobile: boolean;
```

so you can set its value in the component layout:

```
<app-filter-details (backClicked)="goBack()" [whiteBackground]="true">
    <filter-details-title>
        {{ contentOfDetailsTitle }}
    </filter-details-title>
    <filter-details-content>
        <app-whatever-content [showInMobile]="false"></app-whatever-component>
    </filter-details-content>
    <filter-details-content-bottomsheet>
        <app-whatever-content [showInMobile]="true"></app-whatever-component>
    </filter-details-content-bottomsheet>
</app-filter-details>
```

and then add an onResize() check:

```
@HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
onResize() {
    if (this.showInMobile === this.mobile()) {
        if (!this.searching) {
            this.searching = true;
            // subscribe to api calls
        }
    } else {
        // unsubscribe if needed
        this.searching = false;
    }
}
```

And you need the private searching var initialised to false:

```
private searching = false;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, it seems that if some api calls are made from other components inside that one this calls would be done twice unless this showInMobile value is propagated. It might end up being a nightmare propagating this value all the time.